# Expression.Convert(..., someGenericType) throws ArgumentException when used with generic type

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I have this method, using `Expression`s to create fields getters:

```
public static Func<object, T> CreateFieldValueGetter<T>(this Type declaringType, FieldInfo fieldToGet) {
    var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    // ArgumentException if declaringType describes generic-type:
    var cast = Expression.Convert(paramExp, declaringType);
    var body = Expression.Field(cast, fieldToGet);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, T>>(body, paramExp).Compile();
}
```

It works great until I give it a generic type like:

```
class DataErrorNotifyingViewModelBase<TErr> : ViewModelBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo 
    where TErr : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
{
    // ...
}
```

This way:

```
var vm = new DataErrorNotifyingViewModelBase<MyErrorsTypeEnum> ();
var type = vm.GetType();
// ArgumentException:
var getter = type.CreateFieldValueGetter<PropertyChangedEventHandler>(type.GetField("PropertyChanged"));
```

This is the exception I get:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Type GuiHelpers.DataErrorNotifyingViewModelBase`1[TErr] is a generic type definition
```

although simple casting works:

```
var vm = new DataErrorNotifyingViewModelBase<PrintDialogError>();
var obj = (object) vm;
```

So how can I feed it with generic types? Am I limited to non-generic-types only?

## Edit - solution:

[Kaveh Hadjari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33861373/587467) caught it:

Passing `t = typeof (Dictionary<T, int>)` will raise `ArgumentException`, as `t.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsGenericParameter` is `true` (albeit `t.GetGenericArguments()[1].IsGenericParameter` is `false`!)

Passing the type `t = typeof (Dictionary<int, int>)` works fine, becuse no element of the `t.GetGenericArguments()` array has `IsGenericParameter == true`

Comment: Your code does not compile. `type.CreateFieldValueGetter<PropertyChangedEventHandler>(type.GetField("PropertyChanged"));` does not compile as your method is not an extension method. *However*, fixing that, your code works perfectly fine. Please show us *exactly* the code you're using.

Comment: Can't repro the issue; seems to be working fine for me. Perhaps you simplified the example too much?

Comment: Please see this simplified fiddle showing that your `CreateFieldValueGetter` method actually works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iVTzio

Comment: @Rob, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic type is a template for many different specialized types, and at runtime theres a difference between the  generic type and the "instanced" types. A possible reason the call to Expression.Convert might be failing could be you're providing it with the type of the generic version and not with a specialized version with type variables set.

Update: I imagine there's a good reason this method would never work with generic types. Consider the case if the type variable is used as type for a field in the generic class. Since the type size (reference, Boolean, short, int, long, etc) could be variable it would mean that it could offset the memory address of other fields in different specializations of the generic class in a variable way. How would you know in advance which field length thus address offset would be the case if all the variables where not set? You couldn't and therefor we can't determine the the address of the field we might want to create a getter for. The only solution would be to actually create a getter that would rely on using reflection on each object you call the getter with, which would incur higher costs than imagined and if you are happy with that solution you might be as well have a single method that gets the value of the field using reflection without actually creating these getters in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

> "Am I limited to non-generic-types only?"

No, of course not. The error message is clear, though not consistent with the code example you provided. You seem to be passing for the type the original generic type definition (i.e. with an unspecified value for the type parameter), not the constructed generic type (i.e. with a specified value for the type parameter).

Unfortunately, without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know precisely what you've done wrong. All I can say is that you did do something wrong. If you want more specific advice than that, please edit your post so that it includes a good code example.

For what it's worth, here's a complete code example that demonstrates your method working fine with a generic type:

```
class A<T>
{
    public int field1;
    public T field2;
    public event EventHandler Event1;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A<bool> a = new A<bool>();
        Func<object, int> field1Getter =
            CreateFieldValueGetter<int>(a.GetType(), a.GetType().GetField("field1"));
        Func<object, bool> field2Getter =
            CreateFieldValueGetter<bool>(a.GetType(), a.GetType().GetField("field2"));
        Func<object, EventHandler> event1Getter =
            CreateFieldValueGetter<EventHandler>(a.GetType(), a.GetType()
                .GetField("Event1", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance));
    }

    static Func<object, T> CreateFieldValueGetter<T>(Type declaringType, FieldInfo fieldToGet)
    {
        var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        // ArgumentException if declaringType describes generic-type:
        var cast = Expression.Convert(paramExp, declaringType);
        var body = Expression.Field(cast, fieldToGet);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, T>>(body, paramExp).Compile();
    }
}
```

The only wrinkle here is that to obtain the field for the event, you have to specify the `BindingFlags` appropriate to that field (in particular, it's non-public so the default search of `GetField()` won't find it). The code you showed does this incorrectly, but it doesn't explain the exception you're getting.